# How to tamper cookie

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I just wanted to know how to tamper cookie (just for knowledge purposes :-)). I have created one application and tried to tamper the cookie, but it's not working.

**Code:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.Cookies["myCookie"] != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");

    }
    else
    {

        HttpCookie storeData = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
        storeData["name"] = "Arin";
        storeData["color"] = "Blue";
        storeData.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(storeData);
        Response.Redirect("Default2.aspx");
    }
}
```

**Code(Default2.aspx):**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie storeData = Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
    string myString= storeData["name"];
    TextBox1.Text = myString;
}
```

**Saved Cookie Contents:**

```
myCookie
name=Arin&color=Blue
localhost/
1024
1178851840
29993085
467738336
29992884
*
```

When I run the code, it's creating the cookie. Also, next time it's checking if the cookie exists: if yes then it's redirecting to default2.aspx page, and I am getting name in the text box.

But when I am tampering the cookie - let's say when I am changing Arin to Arinzzzl - it's not getting reflected. The Application is considering no cookie name "myCookie" exists and is creating a new cookie.  Thus I am not getting Arinzzz in Default2.aspx. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to play with cookies, use the "Add N Edit Cookies" plug-in on Firefox.

Comment: but as he said for information. why that is not working if u just change it manually?

Answer (score 0):

do you actually end up with 2 cookies saved to your hard drive? if so, you should be able to compare the 2 and see what is different.

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on both ends and see what's going on, and also let us know HOW you're tampering the cookie.  I wrote a simple example doing just as you said, tampered the cookie with the Web Developer plugin in Firefox (View Cookies -> Edit Cookie), and then reloaded the page, and the tampered data was displayed.

This question sounds like it would be better answered by debugging more.  I'm guessing that you're using a tool/method to tamper the cookie that is invalidating it, or you have some program logic that is recreating the cookie when you are not expecting it to.

Also, you can see the contents of the cookie being sent in both directions (request and response) with another firefox plugin called Live HTTP Headers to see if there's an issue with it not being sent back to the server.  This plugin will show you all headers being sent with requests and responses, including all cookies.

[Web Developer plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60)

[Live HTTP Headers plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3829)

Comment: I am not using any tool,just changing the value in notepad and saving it.I think application should check if the cookie exists or not,if it existst then it should take the tampered value.Correct me if I am wrong